How to display an image directly within a widget using Flutter's home_widget?
I’m using Flutter with home_widget. I want to display an image directly in the widget that appears on the home screen. How can I achieve this?
So far, I’ve only managed to display the image when the app is open and settings are being adjusted. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to show the image on the small widget itself.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
